# Finding a coefficient matrix to maximize a given variable under some constraints

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, systems-of-equations

Considering a linear system of the form:

[image]

Is there a method to find the coefficient matrix such that $\mu_F$ is maximal/minimal under some constraints (e.g., $0<c_j^i<1$ and $\sum_{i}c_j^i=1$ $\forall$ $i,j$)?

Note that we can assume the matrix is non-singular.

Comment: You could use Cramer's rule.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I considered using Cramer's rule, however, this turns into a new issue of maximizing one determinant while minimizing another. Perhaps this approach is easier...though I'm unsure how to go about it exactly.

Comment: It would be nice to know which symbols are unknowns and which are given.

Comment: For the problem at hand, we could ideally solve without any knowledge of values in the coefficient matrix (aside from the aforementioned constraints). Energies (Ej) are also unknown, however, some typical values could be plugged to make things easier.

Comment: Which $\mu$'s are known?

Comment: Values for $\mu$ are also unknown. Though $\mu_F$ is the only value we care about maximizing.

Comment: Then you don't have a linear system. You have a *bilinear* system.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100724/discussion-between-nathan-and-rodrigo-de-azevedo).

Comment: The problem is ill-posed. The coefficient matrix can be made singular, and any $\mu_F$ can solve the problem.

Comment: For the given problem, we are dealing with a linearly independent system by assumption (now added to the description).